# Angular 2 system-config.ts doesn't seem to be working with my app specific barrels

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular-cli

Here is my system-config.ts:

```
'use strict';

// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
  'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'moment': {
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  'ng2-bootstrap': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js'
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/photos'
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

I am able to import all the modules EXCEPT for the app specific barrels.

So, `import { AlertComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';` works just fine.

However, `import { PhotoService } from 'app/shared';` does not.

I am exporting correctly because if I do `import { PhotoService } from '../../shared';` it works.

Can someone help me out?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be a relative path.

```
import { PhotoService } from './app/shared';
```

That's why `../../*` works. Doesn't have anything to do with system.